# if else statement reacting to a toggle class Javascript

Tags: javascript

Last question I'm asking. I'm trying yo get my audio to play when my classes toggle but I don't know what if else statement to use.

html:

```
    <section id="sound">
        <img id="speaker" src="img/mic.svg">
        <section>
            <div class="one"></div>
            <div class="two"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
        </section>
    </section>
```

css:

```
    #sound {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    margin: 5em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
}

#sound div {
    width: 0.3em;
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.one {
    margin-top: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.oneanimated {
    height: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

javascript:

```
var backgroundtelegrafisch = document.getElementById("backgroundtelegrafisch");
var sound = document.getElementById("sound");
var one = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
var oneanimated = document.getElementsByClassName("one");

function animatie () {
  one[0].classList.toggle("oneanimated");
  two[0].classList.toggle("twoanimated");
  three[0].classList.toggle("threeanimated");

  if (one == oneanimated){
      backgroundtelegrafisch.play();
  } else {
      backgroundtelegrafisch.pause();
      console.log("test");
  }

}
sound.addEventListener("click", animatie);
```

The console.log never appeared, so the else statement never occurs. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can fix it by making `one == oneanimated` = `false`.

Comment: There are two reasons why this might be happening. Either `one == oneanimated`, so your code will enter the `if` conditional rather than the `else` conditional, or you're never actually calling the `animatie()` function, meaning you won't see any output. My guess is the latter, as it's one character off `animate` -- you may have made a typo when naming/calling the function.

Comment: like this?:

if (one == oneanimated = false){
      backgroundtelegrafisch.play();
  } else {
      backgroundtelegrafisch.pause();
      console.log("test");
  }

Comment: No, I am calling the function (using a clickevent). Animatie is the dutch word for animate. (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: Can you please update your question so that it shows **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There are **multiple** reasons why it might not be working, and it's impossible to tell which from your above code. Are you getting any errors in the console? What happens if you `console.log('test')` as the first line of the function?

Comment: So probably the first thing you mentioned seems to be the case. How should I fix this? using an entire different if condition?

Comment: Updated the question with html, css and all the used javascript.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, and the console displays nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing anything in the console is because, well, the `if` always succeeds. You do this:

```
var one = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
var oneanimated = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
```

...which means `one` and `oneanimated` are exactly the same as each other. You then do this:

```
if (one == oneanimated){
    backgroundtelegrafisch.play();
} else {
    backgroundtelegrafisch.pause();
    console.log("test");
}
```

Can you see the problem now? You're comparing `one` and `oneanimated`, and since they're the same (as we saw earlier) the code will always hit the `backgroundtelegrafisch.play();` line instead of going into the `else`.

Instead of trying to compare `one` to `oneanimated`, you should instead do this:

```
if (one[0].classList.contains("oneanimated")){
    backgroundtelegrafisch.play();
} else {
    backgroundtelegrafisch.pause();
    console.log("test");
}
```

The `contains` method of `classList` checks if the element has the specified class.

Comment: Pointing out the reason why it doesn't work is only half of an answer. You  need to explain how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah that's a good point, idk why I did that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ah man, finally. Sorry for making such a lame mistake... Thank you for your help.

Comment: @H0ndman2 No worries man :) If my answer solved your question don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer :)